# Is there a way to install a NodeRed node in a remote server?

Tags: node.js, node-red

I have tried to use the POST /nodes since the documentation says it support the path where the node is located, https://nodered.org/docs/api/admin/methods/post/nodes.
But the POST /nodes only works when the server is running in localhost, does anyone know if is possible install the node in a remote server using the http api?

Here is an example of the POST that I have tried:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -i http://REMOTE_SERVER_HOSTNAME:1880/nodes --data '{"module": "/tmp/testRemoteInstall"}'
```

Comment: [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63363349/edit) to show exactly what you have tried. There is not enough information here to help you.

Comment: That helps a little, but it's still not great.

Comment: That is the command that I have tried, I am trying to install my own node it was developed my me (it is not in the store), the remote installation for nodes that are in the store works using the HTTP API, but in the documentation says:
module: Either the name of the node module to install from the npm repository, or a full path to a directory containing the node module. Note: this api does not support the full range of module specifiers used by npm such as .tgz files or version qualifiers. It is the reason why I am trying to install my own node using the HTTP API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the doc you pointed to

> **module**:
> Either the name of the node module to install from the npm repository,
> or a full path to a directory containing the node module. Note: this
> api does not support the full range of module specifiers used by npm
> such as .tgz files or version qualifiers.

This means that the `module` argument has to be one of the following:

- The name of a NodeJS module available from npmjs.org
- The path to a local instance of the NodeJS module. (This path must be local to the machine running Node-RED as how else is Node-RED supposed to access a remote file?)

You have 2 choices,

1. publish the module you want to install to npmjs (or another NodeJS repository and make sure the npm on the server is properly configured to install from there)
2. copy the node's directory to the same machine as Node-RED before passing the local path as the value of `module`

Comment: This point is not specific in the documentation
The path to a local instance of the NodeJS module. (This path must be local to the machine running Node-RED as how else is Node-RED supposed to access a remote file?)
Also what is the reason to expose that HTTP API if it only works for the local machine, it does not have sense.

Comment: Feel free to submit a pull request to update the doc

Comment: Because nodes are usually installed from npmjs.org, rather than the local filesystem